# Angular translate innerHTML with params

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I would like to translate a source text containing `<a>` tag with `url` param, the string text example:

```
STRING_TEXT = 'some text <a href={{url}}>some link name</a>'
```

I know there it is possible to translate

```
<div [innerHTML]="'STRING_TEXT' | translate"></div>
```

as described in [docs](http://github.com/ngx-translate/core#plugins).

but how I could include `url` param in this situation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`translate` pipe takes parameter object which is context for the translation message, you can pass this param as:

`<div [innerHTML]="'STRING_TEXT' | translate: {url: someVariableOnComponent}"></div>`

See [the docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive)